# Spring Boot App - Could not resolve placeholder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app which imports an external library. I am reading the spring.xml in the dependency that I have imported. It is throwing an error because it is looking for "propDir" which I have not defined. I see an error "Invalid bean definition with name .... Could not resolve placeholder 'propDir'"

```
<value>file:${propDir}/env-config.properties</value>
```

I have seen another spring boot app import the same dependency and it starts just fine. When I debugged the start sequence and saw the value of propDir , I saw that it  was not substituted and I see "file:${propDir}/env-config.properties" in the created bean.

I have searched the app , but haven't really figured out how the other app is not throwing the error. Is there a piece of config that I am missing?

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify a value for propDir.

This can be done either by jvm argument like 
`-DpropDir=nameoffoldertouse` 
or via a properties file loaded via a [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html).

Other applications that rely on this bean may have a default hidden away.

It is likely that the bean relying on this value will need it to guarantee its correct behaviour, if you do not want to provide this property do not rely on the bean that uses it.

Comment: Thanks @UserF40. I don't need the property to be loaded , also don't have a folder with properties. In the other app that I was referring to , the folder is not provided and when I looked at the constructed bean , I saw this value being set in the variable - ${propDir}/env-config.properties. It did not have propDir substituted.

Answer (score 1):

Properties to a spring boot application can be passed using different ways, very likely for the other application the property for "propDir" is I believe getting passed as one of the ways specified in this documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: the property is not passed and I inspected the loaded bean. It just had the placeholder defined. I'm trying to see how the bean is created with the property being set. Also in this case the bean is loaded from spring.xml and no annotations are used.